# "ERROR: URI has an authority component " in GWT Envioronment

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt

I've just setup my environment (AppEngine using Java) using the Google 
Plugin for Eclipse.

When I try to Run/Debug my Project as a Web Application, I get an "URI 
has an authority component error", see exception stack below:

Has anyone else had this issue?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.createEntryForUrl(ResourceOracleImpl.java:164)
    com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1017)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:557)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:443)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1083)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show us the URI in question, i.e., the URL being used?

Comment: What does you classpath looks like? Are you using a network folder?

Comment: Let me guess; you use an Oracle JDBC URL with the user/password into the URI?

Comment: Yeah.. I use JDBC URL. This is the additional error message: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.

Comment: Well, I don't know how GWT works but it seems like it doesn't like at all that you specify user/pass info in your URI here; you need to get this info out of it and authenticate in code instead

Comment: I've got the same problem though I do not use any URI explicitly in my code. Though, as @ThomasBroyer suggested, I use a network drive.